# how to update mysql with inputs and checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

and with this form: (select * from mp3 aktif = '0')

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<input readonly type="text" name="id" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>" />
<input type="text" name="baslik" value="<?=$haciosman['baslik']?>
<input type="checkbox" name="secilen[]" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>">
<input type="submit" name="onay" value="Onayla" />
```

I can set "aktif to 1" for each row that i checked. but i want to update "baslik" too! how can i update each "baslik" with that php code?

Comment: Google site:stackoverflow Sql injection.

Comment: omg i know it has injections but its just a local thing. not for public

Comment: Fyi it is really hard to read non-english variable names. Makes my head hurt at least. Maybe that's why no answers?

Comment: @Byron: I think the overall ESL issue is causing it. I'm guessing the user wants to update the `baslik` field along with each `set aktif = 1` update, but isn't quite getting the point across. Additionally, only one checkbox field? Sort of lonely isn't it? I can assume that there are multiple checkboxes made from the `select * from mp3` statement, but is that the case?

Comment: not only one checkbox. there are many checkboxes im reapating baslik, checkbox and id with "while"

Comment: @commentators-and-possible-answerers: Maybe his previous question helps to understand the context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563765/checkbox-php-and-update-mysql

Comment: @Ronnie: perhaps your examples should reflect your real code. Or perhaps you should reference the original question, which seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE mp3 
             SET 
                 aktif = '1', 
                 baslik = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['baslik']) ."' 
             WHERE id = '$zuha'");
```

But this is similar to what you already have in your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563765/):

> ```
> mysql_query("update mp3 set aktif = '1', 
>                               baslik = '$_POST[baslik]' 
>                where id = '$_POST[id]'")
> ```

The only difference now is that you make the query in a loop and use a different ID variable.

My comments on your code in your original question stay the same. ( ;) )

P.S.: Introduced [`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-escape-string.php) for a little security.

**UPDATE:** Ok I think I got your problem now. You basically want to create an input field collection for every entry in your database, something like this:

```
<form name="form" method="post">
<table>

<?php while($haciosman = ($query)):?>
<tr>
   <td><input readonly type="text" name="id" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="baslik[<?php echo $haciosman['id'] ?>]" value="<?=$haciosman['baslik']?> </td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="secilen[]" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>">

</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?> 

</table>
<input type="submit" name="onay" value="Onayla" />
</form>
```

You just define another the names of the text fields as arrays `baslik[$haciosman['id']]`, similar as you did for the checkboxes but this time you specify the array key which is the ID of the record.

Then you PHP code you can access this array (`$_POST['baslik']` contains an array now) like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['onay'])) {
  foreach  ($_POST['secilen'] as $zuha) {
    $olay = mysql_query("UPDATE mp3 
                         SET 
                            aktif = '1', 
                            baslik = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['baslik'][$zuha]) ."' 
                         WHERE id = '$zuha'");
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

You should really read the [official short introduction to forms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php), follow the links in this article and in general read the official documentation to get more insight in how to work with PHP.

Comment: yes but this is not updating each row. its only updating one row. ive 3 rows. when i use this query baslik is duplicating. lets change words! "baslik" is "NAME" ok? I have 3 rows! I want to edit 3 row's names. when i click submit 3 rows gets same name

Comment: @Ronnie Chester Lynwood: Of course they do because you only have one NAME input field. If you want to update every three names you have to provide three name input fields, similar to the select boxes.

Comment: <?
while ($haciosman = mysql_fetch_array($veliaht)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td width="42" height="31"><input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>" /></td>
    <td width="271"><label>
      <input type="text" name="baslik" value="<?=$haciosman['baslik']?>" />
    </label></td>
    <td width="168"><?=$haciosman['sarkisozu']?></td>
    <td width="171"><?=$haciosman['ekleyen']?></td>
    <td width="170">
<input type="checkbox" name="secilen[]" value="<?=$haciosman['id']?>">
 <? } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="onay" value="Onayla" />

im using this

Comment: @Ronnie Chester Lynwood: I created somehting similar. Have a look at my updated answer and compare.

Comment: FINALLY!

   <td><input type="text" name="baslik[<?=$haciosman['id']?>]" value="<?=$haciosman['baslik']?>" /> </td>

with this it worked out! MAAAANY MANY MANY MANY MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!! I promise I will read as much as I can. thaank you!!

Comment: @Ronnie Chester Lynwood: Ah yes, I forgot to echo the ID value! God catch! :) I am glad that it works now :) If it helped you, you should mark the answer as accepted then.